# start(n) vs starting(n)

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Here is a song lyric:

> At the starting of the week
>   At summit talks you'll hear them speak (DJ SHADOW_SİX DAYS)

I am wondering if the following sentences have the same meaning:

> At the ***starting*** of the week
>   At summit talks you'll hear them speak
>
> At the ***start*** of the week
>   At summit talks you'll hear them speak

which is the most correct usage: start or starting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to talk about a piece of machinery starting to operate, then **starting** is the only option.

> Locked rotor torque test is not done on wound rotor motors but on squirrel cage induction motors to determine the torque developed at the starting of the motor. [Electrical machines](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=JKsH_3AzYMMC&pg=PA254&dq=%22at%20the%20starting%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwqsrP9pXZAhUN448KHZO1AOUQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22at%20the%20starting%20of%22&f=false)

When you want to talk about the start of a period of time, as in your question, **start** is the best choice and, in my opinion, **starting** sounds wrong. This [NGram](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=JKsH_3AzYMMC&pg=PA254&dq=%22at%20the%20starting%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwqsrP9pXZAhUN448KHZO1AOUQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22at%20the%20starting%20of%22&f=false) shows that **starting** is used, but it is very uncommon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have never heard of Google NGram before.

İt seems pretty useful for checking the usage of the English words.

Extra thanks for mentioning about Ngram

Comment: Agreed, though you have to check some individual instances to make sure that it is selecting the right meaning.